# How the depth of a twig template is calculated by SensioLabsInsight

Tags: symfony, twig

I analyzed the quality of my php project with SensioLabsInsight and I get this error:

**Twig templates should not contain business logic**

*Template too complex, depth of 13 is reached but only 5 is allowed.*

for this template :

```
{% macro row(context, blockinfo, chapterContainerClass, chapterHeadingClass, chapterContentClass) %}

{% set step = context.step %}
{% set panel = blockinfo.panel %}
{% set simu = step.simulator %}
<div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}" class="blockinfo-container">
    <div class="blockinfo-label">
    <h2>{{ blockinfo.label }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="blockinfo-chapters">
        {% for chapter in blockinfo.chapters %}
        {%- if chapter.displayable or (step.dynamic and context.script == 1) or (simu.dynamic and step.id == 0) -%}
        <div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}" class="chapter-container {{ chapterContainerClass }}" data-chapter-id="{{ chapter.id }}">
            <div class="chapter-label {{ chapterHeadingClass }}">
                <h3>
                    {%- if chapter.collapsible -%}
                    <button id="ui-collapse-{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" data-target="#{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}-sections"><span>
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ chapter.label }}
                    {%- if chapter.collapsible -%}
                    </span></button>
                    {% endif %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}-sections" class="blockinfo-chapter-sections {{ chapterContentClass }}{%- if chapter.collapsible %} collapse{%- endif -%}">
                {% for section in chapter.sections %}
                {%- if section.displayable or (step.dynamic and context.script == 1) or (simu.dynamic and step.id == 0) -%}
                <div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}-section-{{ section.id }}" class="section-container">
                    {%- if section.label is not empty -%}
                    <div class="section-label">
                        <h2>{{ section.label }}</h2>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="section-body-container">
                        {%- if section.annotations is not empty %}
                        <div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}-section-{{ section.id }}-annotations" class="section-annotations">
                            {{ simu.paragraphs(section.annotations)|jscode }}
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <div id="{{ step.name }}-panel-{{ panel.id }}-blockinfo-{{ blockinfo.id }}-chapter-{{ chapter.id }}-section-{{ section.id }}-content" class="section-content{%- if section.annotations is not empty %} with-annotations{%- endif -%}">
                            {{ simu.paragraphs(section.content)|jscode }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endmacro %}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem because i don't know how the depth of a twig template is calculated by SensioLabsInsight

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should not use  conditional statements  in twig like :

```
{%- if section.annotations is not empty %}
```

you need to write this statements in controller or in a PHP file something  like this :

```
public function isempty()
{
    if($this->label== "") {
        $mylabel =  "empty";
    }
    else {
        $mylabel = "notempty";
    }

    return $myGender;
}
```

And this is how to avoid business logic in Twig templates

Comment: Tanks for this answer

But why my template has a depth of 13 ?

Comment: I am glad to help , i guess you can use if() and for() only 5 times in a .twig